# How to revert or undo ALLOW_INVALID DATES

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i got an error when im about to insert datas to a column a tutorial in google said to use
`SET SQL_mode= 'ALLOW_INVALID DATES'`
Now I got error 1265 Data truncated for column 'BDAY' And the BDAY column now shows 0000-00-00
How do I revert it back to normal or do I just reinstall mysql?
Thanks so much

Comment: Where did you add it in the first place, look for the my.cnf and see if there is an option `sql-mode="`

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the `sql_mode` on your configuration files, you can run below command on Linux to find the changes:

```
sudo grep -ir "ALLOW_INVALID DATES" /etc/
sudo grep -ir "ALLOW_INVALID DATES" /etc/mysql/
```

Default configuration files on Linux are stored on the `etc` folder.

On your configuration file set `sql_mode` to save it permanently:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

On the `MySQL` command line you can set it for the session and global.

First check using:

```
mysql> show variables like '%sql_mode%';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> show global variables like '%sql_mode%';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you  change it using:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```